# Mac npm erroring with ENOENT

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm a recent convert to Mac from Windows, and currently just trying to get my tools setup.

I first installed node using homebrew, which was giving me errors (same as what I still have). I later removed node using homebrew and installed using the pkg from the node website.

I can access node in the command line and npm. The problem is when I try to install modules on the project locally I get something like:

`npm install grunt-contrib`

```
Error extracting archive { [Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/davidmckeown/dev/adt-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/tmp/phantomjs-1.7.0-macosx.zip']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/davidmckeown/dev/adt-com/node_modules/grunt-contrib/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/tmp/phantomjs-1.7.0-macosx.zip' }
```

Another message just above that contains:

```
npm ERR! phantomjs@0.2.6 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node install.js"` failed with 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@0.2.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.2.1
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-contrib"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/davidmckeown/dev/adt-com
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Any help figuring out what is causing problems here would be fantastic. This happens with other modules too, from what I can tell.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an npm cache issue, try `npm cache clean`

Comment: @generalhenry sadly not, tried that and sudo'ing the npm install but no joy.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the zip file exists at the location npm is trying to unzip it?

Comment: @travis not really sure how I could check that, I think the file is created temporarily and removed during the process?

Comment: Usually there will be a npm log in which ever directory you ran npm from. You may want to read through the log to see if anything pops out. ENOENT is usually thrown by the `fs` module when it can't find a file or directory.

Comment: Might give this a read https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs/issues/15

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`npm cache clean`

or if installed under su

`sudo npm cache clean`

Comment: This also did not work for me on MacOS 10.12.3. Anybody know how to fix this for Xcode 8.2.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue 5 months ago with grunt qunit package  - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-phantomjs/issues/5.

Try to install this specific package:

`sudo npm install grunt-contrib-qunit`

The package that you installed is a bundle of many packages. The qunit package version was not updated explicitly to the latest version in this bundle, that's why clearing the npm cache might solve this issue.